# How to limit impact of a predictor when doing multiple regression?

Tags: r, regression

I am doing some multiple regression using R's `lm()` method. I wonder whether there is an easy way to limit the impact of some predictors. I think `lm()` results give too much weight to certain predictors and I would like to somehow cap coefficients of certain predictors. Is it doable?

Comment: I would read up on LARS and LASSO (via google) and then search for packages with those words in their name (there are many).

Comment: @joran, I'm not expert on LARS & LASSO, but I didn't think they let you constrain only *certain* predictors, but not others. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @gung I believe you are correct, but there's frequently an algorithm/method for everything under the sun these days, so it's entirely possible something like that exists and I don't know about it. But the OP wasn't entirely clear on that, and LARS/LASSO are close enough to what they describe that I figured it might be helpful.

Comment: If you only have certain predictors that you'd like to constrain, it seems that one way of doing it is via ridge regression, another shrinkage method. First, regress $y$ on the predictors whose impact you'd like to constrain. Then, take the residuals and regress them on the predictors that you don't want to constrain. Effectively, you've projected $y$ into the constrained subspace, then onto the unconstrained subspace. This is spin on the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem.

Comment: Linear regression is essentially a quadratic optimization problem without any constraint. If you really want to have bound constraints on certain coefficients, just solve a constrained quadratic problem. I believe there are some R functions for this purpose.

Comment: I am not being flippant in suggesting just leaving out the variable. A model fitted without a certain predictor is a good counterpart to other models. Unless someone forces you to use just one model, this is a simple alternative to explore.

Comment: @Charlie I don't understand how your method would restrict.  The first set of predictors will have an undiminished effect on the residuals, won't they?  And since the residuals become the link of sorts to the next analysis...it sounds very much like "regular" regression, only stretched out into two stages.  But what do I know....

Comment: @Charlie there is no need to do it in two separate regressions, simply set $\lambda_i I$ with different $\lambda_i$ for each predictor on the ridge regression (this would be the poor man's version of setting different prior variances on the gaussian prior)

Answer (score 2):

> How to limit impact of a predictor when doing multiple regression?

One straightforward way to do this is simply doing a Bayesian regression.

For instance you say:

> I think lm() results give too much weight to certain predictors

This reveals you have a prior belief that those predictors shouldn't have much influence. With a Bayesian model you can explicitly put a stronger prior on some of your parameters, and that will accomplish what you want.

It's worth noticing that Ridge and LASSO can be interpreted as bayesian regressions with a Gaussian and Laplace priors, respectively.

Let me provide you a simple example on how to do this using the [arm R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=arm):

```r
library(arm)                                                       
set.seed(10)                                                       
n <- 100                                                           
x1 <- rnorm (n)                                                    
x2 <- rnorm(n)                                                     
y <- 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(n)                                    

M1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)                                              
display(M1)                                                        
#> lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)
#>             coef.est coef.se
#> (Intercept) 1.02     0.10   
#> x1          2.00     0.10   
#> x2          2.86     0.10   
#> ---
#> n = 100, k = 3
#> residual sd = 0.97, R-Squared = 0.92

# restricting the influnce of x2                                   
M2 <- bayesglm(y ~ x1 + x2, prior.scale=c(Inf, 0.03), prior.df=Inf)
display(M2)                                                        
#> bayesglm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, prior.scale = c(Inf, 0.03), prior.df = Inf)
#>             coef.est coef.se
#> (Intercept) 0.93     0.13   
#> x1          1.95     0.14   
#> x2          2.01     0.11   
#> ---
#> n = 100, k = 3
#> residual deviance = 159.5, null deviance = 1146.1 (difference = 986.6)
#> overdispersion parameter = 1.6
#> residual sd is sqrt(overdispersion) = 1.28
```

The first model `M1` is the simple `lm`. On the second model we we are shrinking `x2` to zero with a tighter prior.

If you want more flexible ways to specify your model, you should check [Stan](http://mc-stan.org) and R packages around it.

Comment: I'd like to hear more.  Is there a single method widely accepted as "Bayesian regression"?

Comment: @rolando2 as a method, yes -- a Bayesian regression is the general method where you set up the prior, the likelihood and then compute the posterior. As a model, there is no general model. You have a wide variety of ways of modeling a problem, different choices of priors etc.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you happen to know of a solid but fairly basic example that you would recommend to newbies in Bayes?

Comment: Grazie!  I will check into it.

Comment: @rolando2 I also provided a simple example here on the answer.